# input value data is not passing using jquery/ajax to Php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get result from Mysql database but I'm getting warning message it's because it's not passing the **html field value** to jquery/ajax method. I think issue is on this line `data : SearchValue,`. So that In my php page it's not getting `$search = $_POST['SearchValue'];` value and showing warning message.

Can anyone tell what is wrong in my code ? Thank You.

**Html Page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#display").click(function() {                
     var SearchValue = $('#txt_name').val();

      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "POST",
            url: "doSearch.php",             
            data : SearchValue,             
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
            success: function(response){                    
                $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
                //alert(response);
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>

<h3 align="center">Manage Student Details</h3>
    <table border="1" align="center">
       <tr>
           <td> <input type="text" name="search" id="txt_name" /> </td>
           <td> <input type="button" id="display" value="Display All Data" /> </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
<div id="responsecontainer" align="center">
```

**Php page:**

```
$search = $_POST['SearchValue'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use Below Code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#display").click(function() {                
 var SearchValue = $('#txt_name').val();
 var str = $( "#form_id" ).serialize();
  $.ajax({    
        //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST",
        url: "doSearch.php?searchValue="+SearchValue,             
        data : str,             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }

    });
});
```

});

Comment: @Sono Jangid I've another issue. I've html form which load the data from mysql database using Jquyer/ajax. Now I want to update this form using Jquyer/Ajax. But again same problem it's not passing the data to php using jquery/ajax. I'm using following code : `$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#UpdateDetails").click(function() {                
   var Value = $(this).serialize();`

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting the form via native method. That means if you click on your submit button the page will be reloading (since in your case you haven't included the form action).

One thing you could do is make a button and a textfield outside of the form and declare its onClick attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<button onclick="doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value)"> Search <button>
```

OR

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<button onclick="doSearch($("#search").val())"> Search <button>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But it's showing the result on the Search page.

Comment: Hello is there any solution ?

Comment: What do you mean it shows the result on the search page?

Comment: Hello Check my Update questions plz.